# trim last matched lines in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

i have a file called ssl.crt

cat ssl.crt

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
dfhdfd
jdfhdjkfh
dfdfdjfdf
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
eryeurer
dhfdfdf
fjdjfh
rery
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
rutyr
fgjhu
rutr
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I want to take only last

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
rutyr
fgjhu
rutr
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

is there an option in terraform?

trying something like this:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert2" {
  private_key      = file("./cert.key")
  certificate_body = file("./cert.crt")
  certificate_chain = file("./cert.crt")
}
```

unfortunately, my certificate_body and certificate_chain both are in a single file (ssl.crt)

from ssl.crt I want to take last matched set (this is cert_body)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
rutyr
fgjhu
rutr
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Probably you could do that, but why not pre-precess the file and split it before tf?

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not able to get the separated file as .chain and .cert.  The only option is I have chain and cert in a single file. somehow separate them and create ACM cert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [regexall](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/regexall.html) for this:

```
locals {
  certs = regexall("(?s)-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----.*?-----END CERTIFICATE-----", file("./ssl.crt"))
}

output "certs" {
  value = local.certs
}
```

Result:

```
Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

last_cert = <<EOT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
rutyr
fgjhu
rutr
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
EOT
```

**Regex Explanation:**

- The `(?s)` is a flag saying that the `.` character should match newlines as well.
- The `.*` matches anything in between the begin/end lines. The `?` in `.*?` makes it a "lazy" match (non-greedy), so it will match as little content as possible in between the begin/end lines (this is what makes it return multiple matches; otherwise it would use the very first BEGIN and the very last END and return everything in between).